# NAT Public ip to that many number of pvt ip

Tags: iptables, routing, nat, dnat

i have a Linux box with two interfaces one with ip 10.10.18.2 and other with ip 192.168.1.2,192.168.1.3 aliased.

A xen host is connected with ip 10.10.18.3 and gateway 10.10.18.2 to this through a switch.

on Xen host 2 vms are running with ip 10.10.18.43 and 10.10.18.44 with gateway 10.10.18.3 (that of xen host).

**Requirement:**
NAT 192.168.1.0/24 to 10.10.18.0 of corresponding vms.

**if i do DNAT;** ie every packets with destination 192.168.1.2 to 10.10.18.43 then will the reply from 10.10.18.43  reach requesting ip,since packets received at 10.10.18.43 will be having source ip as that of requesting ip and thus rejecting packet from 10.10.18.43 at requesting end.

**If i do snat** 10.10.18.43 to 192.168.1.2 to fix above problem then how will DNAT ing 192.168.1.3 to 10.10.18.44 work with the above existing SNAT rule?

Comment: DNAT automatically handles both way. You don't have to take care of the return path, it is done automatically.

Comment: @BatchyX i was not getting reply with out SNAT.